# facebook registration plugin

Tags: database, facebook, plugins, save, registration

I have a problem with facebook Registration social plugin.
If i put this plugin on my site, it possible to store permanently the data inserted by the user, or prefilled, in my database?
I would use this plugin like an alternative to register users on my site, so i need to save registration data in my database.
But i don't find policies information about storing user data in database.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a helpful link: http://www.9lessons.info/2011/01/user-signup-using-facebook-data.html